# Finding correct articles for SLR from different databases?

Tags: publications, research-process, literature-search, review-articles

I have to do a systematic literature review (SLR) as part of a university course. I have found all search terms etc, but now I have to narrow down the search to **research articles**. I've been stuck for a week, since each database has its own name for these papers and I'm not sure which publication/source type to select from each database, so they are all correct and comparable.

Below I have listed each database and the different publications they have:

- ACM: *"proceedings"* vs *"journals"* vs *"research articles"*
- Google Scholar: *"review articles"* vs well, *non-review articles*
- IEEE Xplore: *"conferences"* vs *"journals"*
- ScienceDirect: "research articles" vs "review articles"
- Scopus: *"article"* vs *"conference paper"* vs *"conference proceeding"* vs *"journal"*
- Springer: *"conference paper"* vs *"article"* vs *"conference proceeding"*

Thanks for any advice.
Best regards

PS: If I had to choose, I'd take ACM (research articles), Google Scholar (review articles), IEEE Xplore (journals), ScienceDirect (research articles), Scopus (article), Springer (article)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you seem to be stuck on the term "research articles" as if that describes a specific genre of article. But it does not. It can mean many different things. I suspect that what it means is "peer-reviewed articles" (as opposed to practitioner studies or non-peer-reviewed scholarly articles), **but you will need to clarify from your professor precisely what they mean by the term**. I am sure that they will be able to clarify this for you. Since this is a school assignment, then it really does not matter much what answers you might receive from here (including my answer); what matters is that you correctly understand what your professor means. **So, ask your professor for clarification.**

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer! The professor said it's up to me to find the correct publications....

If you could answer, if I choose the following publications/articles from these databases, I think they are coherent in terms of research quality and usability for a systematic literature review?

ACM (research articles), Google Scholar (review articles), IEEE Xplore (journals), ScienceDirect (research articles), Scopus (article), Springer (article)

Comment: I find it odd that the professor would not clarify such a basic question. But I think you should search for "peer-reviewed articles" in each database. Sorry, but I am not able to check each of the databases you have listed to see what terminology each one uses, but the notion is a peer-reviewed article. These might be both journals and conference articles.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! :)

Comment: @QuarterlyReport, if this answer answers your question, please click the check mark to accept it.